# How to calculate portfolio performance in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've found this question particularly hard to google as the search terms come up with matching results, but not what I'm looking for...

I am trying to calculate the performance of a stock over a given time period using MS Access.

Example Calculation:

- 01.01.2016 Price: 100.00
- 25.02.2016 Price: 110.00

Pseudo Code:

```
Performance = Ending Price/Starting Price - 1
```

As simple as this would be to calculate in Excel, I can't seem to get it done in MS Access. My attempt thus far already fails on the simple task to get the end date. The Failure message is:

> "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression'MoPo_BM_ID'as part of an aggregate function"

**UPDATE:**
I found a [website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd5d802d-33a3-4f43-8d1e-eee069f5a8c3/calculate-stock-return-on-simple-table) that included some code that creates the desired result. The example works fine, but I tried adapting it to my own situation but am getting the error message "At most one record can be returned by this subquery".

```
SELECT x.Mandat_ID, x.BeginPrice, x.EndPrice, ([EndPrice]-[BeginPrice])/[BeginPrice] AS RETURN
FROM (SELECT Mandat_ID,

     (SELECT Value AS BeginDate
      FROM tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP AS P
      WHERE (Mandat_ID = Mandat_ID)
        AND (Date =
               (SELECT MIN(Date) AS Expr1
                FROM tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP AS D
                WHERE (Mandat_ID = Mandat_ID)))) AS BeginPrice,

     (SELECT Value AS BeginDate
      FROM tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP AS P
      WHERE (Mandat_ID = Mandat_ID)
        AND (Date =
               (SELECT MAX(Date) AS Expr1
                FROM tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP AS D
                WHERE (Mandat_ID = Mandat_ID)))) AS EndPrice
   FROM tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP
   GROUP BY Mandat_ID)  AS x
WHERE Mandat_ID=6028;
```

**How can I get it to show me one record?**

Comment: That edited additional query is never going to work. Those subqueries are just plain wrong. Can you show us what Mandat_ID 6028 looks like in the IndexMFP table? As I asked earlier, are there duplicate date entries in the IndexMFP for a single Mandat?

Answer (score 0):

To get the max date to work, you need to group by the other fields in the select. So your query becomes

```
SELECT 
   tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID, 
   tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP.Mandat_ID,tbl_MoPo_BM.Launch_Date, 
   Max([tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP]![Date]) AS End_Date
FROM 
tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP 
INNER JOIN tbl_MoPo_BM ON tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP.Mandat_ID =  
tbl_MoPo_BM.AMSDB_MoPo_Code
GROUP BY 
   tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID, 
   tbl_AMSDB_IndexMFP.Mandat_ID,
   tbl_MoPo_BM.Launch_Date, 
WHERE (((tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID)=107))
```

Without knowing what your value/price field(s) are, whether the Launch_Date is the start date and whether duplicate entries are in your indexMFP table I can't write the rest to give you the answer to your Pseudo Performance calculation.

Comment: I tried using your solution but couldn't get it to work. I now found a bit of extra information on the web which seemed to work in the example (I recreated it) but not when I adapted it to my situation.